# Why does this pumping lemma proof not cover every division of xyz?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I am trying to prove $L =$ {${a^k|k=2^n, n \ge 0}$} is not regular. 
So far I have identifed a string $s = a^{2^p}$, and I've divided $s$ into $xyz$ as follows:

$x = a^l$

$y = a^k$

*(where $k + l \le p$)

$z = a^{2^p-l-k}$

Now, when I start to look at pumping, I first select $i=0$:

$xy^iz = xy^0z = xz = a^la^{2^p-l-k}=a^{2^p-k}$, which is clearly not equivalent to $a^{2n}$. However, I know that there are mistakes in this proof and I have been told that my division of the string $s$ into $xyz$ does not account for all divisions. Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, the pumping lemma is (from Introduction to the Theory of Computation by Michael Sipser)

> If $A$ is a regular language, then there is a number $p$ (the
>   pumping length) where if $s$ is any string in $A$ of length at least $p$, then $s$ may be divided into three pieces, $s = xyz$, satisfying the following conditions:
>
> 1. for each $i ≥ 0, xy^i z \in A$,
> 2. $|y| > 0$, and
> 3. $|xy| \le p$.

When you want to prove that a language is not regular using the pumping lemma, you use a proof by contradiction. You first assume that the given language is regular.

As per the pumping lemma, given a regular language, *there exists* a number $p$ such that *for all* $s$ with length at least $p$, *there exists* a way to partition it in the form $x,y,z$ such that *all* the three conditions hold.

The contrapositive is

*For all* $p\ge1$, *there exists* a string $s$ with length at least $p$, such that *for all* ways to partition $s$ in the form $x,y,z$, *at least* one of the three conditions are false, implies that the language is not regular.

So, to show that $L$ is not regular, you need to show that the appropriate quantifier (existential or universal) for each entity is used correctly.

Initially, you have taken a value $p$, with no assumption. This is in accordance with *for all* $p$.

Then, you have chosen a string $s$ with length at least $p$. This is in accordance with *there exists* a string $s$, i.e., a single instance of a string satisfying the rest of the statement is sufficient.

Now, you need to consider *all ways* of partitioning $s$ in the form $x,y,z$, and show that always, at least one of the three statements of the lemma is false.

So, you have partitioned it into $x=a^l, y=a^k, z=a^{{2^p}-l-k}$. As of now, there are no assumptions on the values $l$ and $k$ can take, except that they are non negative, which is as required. To force a contradiction, you need to try to show that all the statements of the lemma do hold. Statement 2 states that $|y|\gt0$. So, if it were true, we must have $k\gt0$. Statement 3 states that $|yz|\le p$. If it were true, we must have $k+l\le p$.

Finally, Statement 1 must be true if $L$ is regular, so $xy^iz\in L$ for all $i\ge0$ must be true. It is sufficient thus to show that it is false for any one value of $i$. I choose $i=2$. So, we must have $a^la^{2k}a^{{2^p}-l-k}=a^{{2^p}+k}\in L$ for all possible values of $l$ and $k$ except as per the previously imposed restrictions.

Now, we have
$$k\gt0\implies k\ge1$$
$$2^p+k\ge 2^p+1\gt 2^p\tag1$$

$$k+l\le p$$
But $l\ge 0$, so we have
$$k\le p$$
$$2^p+k\le 2^p+p\tag2$$

But we have $$p\lt 2^p$$

for all $p\ge 1$, which is the set of all allowed values of $p$. So, $(2)$ becomes,
$$2^p+k\le 2^p+p\lt 2^p+2^p=2^{p+1}\tag3$$

From $(1)$ and $(3)$,

$$2^p\lt 2^p+k \lt2^{p+1}$$

As $2^p+k$ lies strictly between consecutive powers of $2$, it cannot be a power of $2$ itself. So, $a^{2^p+k}\notin L$, and we have a contradiction as desired.

Thus, $L$ is not regular.

---

In your proof, the initial steps are all correct, all you need to do is to show why the string cannot lie in the language, using an appropriate value of $i$, as shown in this answer. Moreover, choosing $i=0$ is not straightforward. For $i=2$, I argued that $2^p\gt p$. For $i=0$, you will need to use $2^{p-1}\gt p$, which is not true if $p=1$.